# How can we make jQuery GridView date range search

Tags: php, jquery, yii

Following is my Gridview widget code. I want to make search through this jquery gridview by entering two date range values. date range values are getting from datepicker.

```
<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
'id'=>'printstatusforlocal-grid',
'dataProvider'=>$model->searchprogress(),
'filter'=>$model,
'columns'=>array(

'order_id',
'albumname',            
'orderdate',
'username',
array('header'=> 'Synchronized',
'name'=>'synchronize',
'value'=>'$data->Syncronize',
 ),
array(
'class'=>'CButtonColumn',
 ),
 ),
 )); ?>


 This is my gridview widget.I want to make a date range search through this? 
        My date picker chosing code is following..


<script src="<?php echo  Yii::app()->baseUrl.'/js/jquery.easing.1.3.js';?>"></script> <script src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>/js/jquery-ui-1.10.4.min"  type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
$(function() {
$( "#datepicker1, #datepicker2" ).datepicker({
dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
});
```

```
 From Date<input type="text" id="datepicker1" name="fromdate" >&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
 To Date<input type="text" id="datepicker2" name="todate" >
```

How can I make date range search using this?I have  made a correction in my question.Help me please..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly:

- date field in your DB table is `orderdate`
- you want to search records comparing `orderdate` to `fromdate` and `todate`

In this case you must add those two attributes to your model class:

```
public $fromdate;
public $todate;
```

Then declare them as safe in model rules (in all scenarios or in search only):

```
public function rules () {
    return array() {
        ...
        array('fromdate, todate', 'safe', 'on'=>'search'),
        ...
    }
}
```

Add those attributes to your grid filter:

```
'columns' => array(
    ...
    array(
        'name' => 'orderdate',
        'filter' => $this->widget( 'zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDatePicker', array(
                'model'          => $model,
                'attribute'      => 'fromdate',
            ), true ) . $this->widget( 'zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDatePicker', array(
                'model'          => $model,
                'attribute'      => 'todate',
            ), true ),
    ),
    ...
),
```

Then add `compare` to `searchprogress()` method:

```
$criteria->compare('orderdate', $model->fromdate);
$criteria->compare('orderdate', $model->todate);
```

Note. Your date format in DB table and in attribute value must be in the same format (e.g. Y-m-d). If you store timestamp in DB, then you need something like this:

```
$criteria->compare('orderdate', strtotime($model->fromdate));
```

With small improvements to my example code you can easily implement search by date period. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

The jquery ui datepicker has some api. So i'd use [`onSelect`](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-onSelect) method:
*on datepicker select* we reroute to the the same controller/action with appended `date` GET parameter:

```
<?php 
   $url= $this->createUrl($this->route());// to go to the same controller/action 
   ...
?>
<script> 
$("#datepicker1, #datepicker2").datepicker({
  dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
// we append the current value to reroute
  onSelect: function(dateText) {location.href = "<php echo $url;?>&date="+ this.value;},
});
</script>
```

Then in your Grid you might pass `$_GET['date']` into the `searchprogress()` method:

```
<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
'id'=>'printstatusforlocal-grid',
'dataProvider'=>$model->searchprogress($_GET['date']),
 ...
```

Now you need to modify this method to smth. like this:

```
public function searchprogress($date=null)
{
    $criteria=new CDbCriteria;
    $criteria->compare('id',$this->id); 
    ...
    if ($date)        
        $criteria->compare('date', $date); // compare models with this passed parameter
    else  
        $criteria->compare('date', $this->date);     // default comparison
// if you want some range comparison
    if ($date) $criteria->addCondition('Begin >= "' . $date . '" ');
    if ($date) $criteria->addCondition('End<= "' . $date . '" '); 
    ...
    return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
        'criteria'=>$criteria, 
    ));
```

Now the `searchprogress()` method will return the DataProvider with data ranged according to the entered datepicker value.

Comment: @Sujith K, i've not taken in notice the two parameters for begin and end. But you might slightly modify the code to make it work for both datepicker values.

Comment: @Sujith K, another way to pass 2 datepickers' parameters is by wrapping datepickers in a form, adding submit button to the form and reroute to the same conrtoller/action.